# many icons are grayed in workbench 6.3.6 on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mysql-workbench

I just installed mysql workbench 6.3.6 on ubuntu 16.04.

When I connect to db, many icons on the top are disabled ( grayed ) and doesn't show any default schemas (such as sys and etc ) on the left 
as you see in the figure, so I cannot create db and tables in workbench.

I followed this youtube video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6p2OU491Ss 
and many icons are activated ( not grayed in the video ) in workbench.

[image]

I created mytest db manually in command line and icons in both local instance and mytest are grayed in workbench. But I can connect to mysql in command line with username root and password that I reset.

[image]

This is because Test connection failed in workbench. don't know why.

[image]

FYI, when I reset root password, I used this command:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD('newpassword'), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='%';
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no valid connection, that's why the buttons are disabled (and hence shown in gray). Open MySQL Workbench with valid credentials and everything should start working as you expect. The connection test error seems to indicate that your MySQL server is not running.